# reading empty rows between data using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

my excel sheet has following data

```
1234556  gold  
1234456  silver  
null     null   
4455455  platinum
```

how will i read this entire empty rows using missing cellpolicies? i tried coding using missing cellpolicy but couldn't get the required output.

```
for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
            List cellTempList = new ArrayList();
            Row r = hssfSheet.getRow(rowNum);

            int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), 2);
            if(r.getRowNum()==0||r.getRowNum()<=i){
                continue; //just skip the rows if row number is 0 or 1
            }
            for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
                Row row = hssfSheet.getRow(rowNum);
                Cell cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                 // Cell cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);

                //if(row.getCell(cn)==null){

                //cellTempList.add("Null");


                if(cell.getCellType()==cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC && cell.getColumnIndex()==0 )
                {//call phone number validation method
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
                    String cellValue=df.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    cellTempList.add(cellValue.toString());
                    logger.debug("Adding cell having string to "+cellTempList);
                }
                else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                {//call string validation method
                    cellTempList.add(cell.toString());
                    logger.debug("Adding cell having string to "+cellTempList);

                }
                else{cellTempList.add(cell.toString()+"-");
                //errorList.add(cell.getErrorCellValue());
                errorList.add(cell.getRowIndex() + "$" + cell.getColumnIndex()+ "$"  );
                System.out.println(errorList);
                }

            }cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
        }

    } System.out.println(cellDataList);
```

using this code its printing only 2 rows above empty row leaving 4th row to print..? help me

Comment: Did u fill null into the cell of excel file as u mention?

Comment: no its just to indicate row is blank

Answer (score 0):

I used Apache POI a long time ago, but to read empty cells I did something like this

```
Cell cell=row.getCell(index);
if(cell!=null && cell.toString().isEmpty){
 System.out.println("The cell is empty");
}
```

And in order to get the last row, so you know kow many maximum columns there are : `sheet.getLastRowNum()`

So now all you have to do is to get the index of the first row and just do a loop from the first to the last. Getting first the row and then the cell, you get empty cells too, but you can decide what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private String getCellValue(Cell cell) {
        if (cell == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            return cell.getNumericCellValue() + "";
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
            return cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "";
        }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR){
            return cell.getErrorCellValue() + "";
        } 
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything is working right except the for loop you have used.

instead of `for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++)`

you should use `for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum <= rowEnd; rowNum++)`

Actually the loop is exiting before reaching to the last row. Remember the rowEnd as I understand is nothing but `sheet.getLastRowNum();` and it is zero index based. So in this case when you have actually 4 rows, it will give you just 3, and on execution, the loop is executing just for row 0, row 1, row 2 and then exit.